# use jQuery to get text from current div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a small search engine querying the database for a list of names. The engine returns a maximum of 5 names. There is a button next to each each person's name. When the button is clicked, my jQuery code is supposed to add only that person's name to a comma separated list. Currently, it is adding every name that the engine pulls up. Im assuming I need to utilize the `this` command somehow. I feels as if my div isn't properly being selected.

The Question: how do you access the text of a paragraph that exists in the same class as the button?

The paragraph and button are enclosed by a class. The paragraph has a class. The button has a class.

```
//jQuery function to add the name to my list of names
$(document).ready(function(){
    var addList = $('.addList');

    $(".addCustomer").on( "click", function() {
        customerToAdd = $('.addIndividual > .searched_name').text(); //here is where the problem lies. it comma separates every name
        addList.val($('.addList').val() + customerToAdd + ', ');
        search.val('');
    });
});
```

And here is my html enclosed in php. This holds the fields that are used by the jQuery above.

```
while($state = mysqli_fetch_assoc($states)) {
$customerid = $state['id'];
$customername = $state['name'];
echo "
    <div class='addIndividual' >
        <p style='float:left;' class='searched_name'>".$customername."
        </p>

        <button type='button' value=".$customername." class='btn btn-default addCustomer'>Assign List to a Class</button>
    </div>  

<hr>";

}
```

Comment: create a hidden input and save there your values. You can access the input with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
$('.addIndividual > .searched_name').text();
```

to

```
$(this).val();
```

OR if not the same as in the customer paragraph (it does seem that it is now):

```
$(this).closest(".addIndividual").find('.searched_name').text();
```

or if the paragraph stays next to the button for sure:

```
$(this).prev().text();
```

Comment: YES!!! thank you! this worked. I had tried using both closest and find, but never together. (and yeah, i meant to delete that id earlier.)

Comment: Just did it! I was just waiting for the minimum 10 minute wait to expire. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have the customer's name in the `value` attribute of the button.  You can just grab it with: `$(this).val()`.

You should also change your button to use `class="addCustomer"` instead of `id="addCustomer"`.  ID's are for unique elements, while a class is for multiple elements.  In your case, you have a button for each customer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `$(".addCustomer").on( ...` create a function like this:

```
function addCustomer(index){
   $('.addIndividual .searched_name_'+index).text();
   // continue the script ...
}
```

Your while loop will now look like this:

```
<p style='float:left;'class='searched_name_".$customerid."'>".$customername."</p>
```

Comment: No. It will return all texts having that class

Comment: Not at all. It will return the text in all inputs having the class `.searched_name` inside the div `.addIndividual`

Comment: It will return more than one text if there are more than one search_name inside

Comment: Then use a function;

Comment: Just take $(this).val()